# Modify shape color inside custom ButtonStyle

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

In my project, I am using my custom shape as a button's label. Now, I am trying to create a custom `ButtonStyle` which changes the custom shape's color whenever a button is currently pressed.

If I were to use a "normal" Button label, e.g. a `Text`, I could do this:

```swift
struct LightGrayButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .black : .red)
    }
}
```

However, `configuration.label` does not have any `Shape` specific view modifiers, making it impossible to alter the color using `.fill` for example.

This is the rest of my code:

```swift
Button {
   action()
} label: {
   RingSegment() // this is my custom shape
}
.buttonStyle(LightGrayButtonStyle()) // I apply my custom button style
```

How can I now change the color of my custom shape inside my custom `ButtonStyle`? Alternatively, how can I make my custom shape respect the provided `foregroundColor` which I *can* set inside the `makeBody` method implemented by my `LightGrayButtonStyle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went for is to apply the `foregroundColor` modifier inside the `makeBody` function and use that color when filling my custom shape.

This is my code:

```swift
// Declare Button Style
struct LightGrayRingSegmentButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .red : .blue)
    }
}


Button {
    action()
} label: {
    RingSegment()
        // respect foregroundColor which we set inside the custom button style
        .fill(.foreground)
}
.buttonStyle(LightGrayRingSegmentButtonStyle())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move all the code inside the `ButtonStyle`

```
struct MyShapeButtonStyle<S: Shape>: ButtonStyle {
    ///Custom Shape
    let shape: S
    ///Default Color
    let color: Color
    ///Uses any Shape
    init(shape: S, color: Color) {
        self.shape = shape
        self.color = color
    }
    ///Default is a `Circle`
    init(color: Color) where S == Circle {
        self.shape = Circle()
        self.color = color
    }
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        //Custom shape
        shape
            //Fill for the shape
            .fill(configuration.isPressed ? .black : color)//Keep the ability to put a label in the button
            .overlay(content: {
                //Keep the ability to have a custom label.
                configuration.label
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            })
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .black : color)
    }
}
```

Then you can pass in any `Shape` and any `Color`.

```
struct CustomButtonShapeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Test") {
                print("test")
            }
            .buttonStyle(MyShapeButtonStyle(color: .red))
            
            Button("Test") {
                print("test")
            }
            .buttonStyle(MyShapeButtonStyle(shape: Rectangle(), color: .blue))
        }
    }
}
```